# reading strikeThrough values from excel cell in php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, strikethrough

While Reading Excel file in php using PHPExcel Library, i can read the font value of a cell whether it is strike through or not using below code

```
foreach($sheetData[$row] as $key=>$value){

$array_key=$key.$row;
$sheetStrikeThrough[$row][$key]=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($array_key)->getFont()->getStrikethrough();}
```

BUT

if a cell have multiple values separated by comma (,) i.e
VAL1, VAL2, VAL3
and only VAL2 is strikeThrough then this library doesn't read the cell as strikeThrough.

How i can find the strikThrough value in a cell even if complete cell isn't strikeThrough then too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979394/phpexcel-cannot-reads-styles-from-xls

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/227

Comment: @ Tim Williams, Thank you very very much! your comments moved me in right direction and now its done! again i would say thank you very much