# getBold on a cell with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, bold

I would like to get if the cell is bold or not when importing cell value and other properties into database with PHPExcel

`var_dump($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getStyle()->getFont()->getBold());`

I easily get the value, but whenever the cell is bold or not that thing return always false

```
           while($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue() != NULL) {

                $tableCell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();

                //Test if the field is in bold
                if ($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getStyle()->getFont()->getBold())
                {
                    $header = true;
                }else
                {
                    $header = false;
                }

                //Test if the field need to be displayed
                if (preg_match($regPattern, $tableCell))
                    $displayOnQuestion = true;
                else
                    $displayOnQuestion = false;

                $inputTableCell = array(
                    "FK_Question" => $idQuestion,
                    "Content" => $tableCell,
                    "Column_Nb" => $nbColumn,
                    "Row_Nb" => $nbRow,
                    "Header" => $header,
                    "Display_In_Question" => $displayOnQuestion,
                    "Creation_Date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
                );`
```

All datas are inserted correctly except the "Header" that will be true if the cell is bold

[Exemple of sheet excel with header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frLp2.jpg)

If anyone can help me to get this, that would be great !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPexcel cannot reads styles from xls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979394/phpexcel-cannot-reads-styles-from-xls)

Comment: Are you loading the file with readDataOnly set to true?

Comment: Is the content of this cell a rich text object?